# Set of integers modulo $2^n$ with operation $x∗y= 4xy+x(−1)^y+y(−1)^x \mod 2^n$ is a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be the set of integers modulo $2^n$ with operation $x∗y= 4xy+x(−1)^y+y(−1)^x \mod 2^n$. Show that $G$ is a cyclic group

Any hints with this? I see the element $1$ has order $2^n$ but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: You mean $1$ has order $2n$?..

Comment: This is a group?  There are inverses?

Comment: I meant mod 2^n. LaTeX messed up sorry

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you show that this is a group?  I.e.  Associative, existence of inverses, that sort of thing?

Comment: But $1\star1=0$...

Comment: @ChrisCuster  How do you see that?  I see $1\star 1=4-1-1=2$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Only in the case $n=1$.

Comment: I know $0$ is the identity. I am struggling to find a general expression for the inverse of an element.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Can you show that this operation is associative?  For $n=1, 2$ can you work it out completely?

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  This appears to be an arbitrary function of two variables.  How do you know that it defines a group structure?

Comment: @lulu Well I am given that it defines a group structure. The problem is to prove that it is cyclic. I have of course tried $n=1,2$ (that is easy). The difficulty for me is doing it generally for any $n$.

Comment: Given by whom?  God?

Comment: @lulu By the question setter. I have proven closure (trivial), associativity and existence of identity. inverses is not so obvious.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the proof of associativity and the existence of inverses.  It's seriously not obvious that this defines a group.

Comment: @lulu I'd rather not to be honest. Proving associativity isn't difficult. It's just a lot of writing. The difficulty here is proving that there exists an element of order $2^n$ (which will give inverses automatically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, I added a proof of associativity and identity.

**Proof of associativity**

$$(x*y)*z = (4xy + x(-1)^y + y(-1)^x)*z = 4(4xy+x(-1)^y + y(-1)^x)z + z(-1)^{4xy + x(-1)^y + y(-1)^x} + (4xy+x(-1)^y + y(-1)^x)(-1)^z = 16xyz + 4xy(-1)^z + 4xz(-1)^y + 4yz(-1)^x + x(-1)^{y+z} + y(-1)^{x + z} + z(-1)^{x+y}$$

Which is symmetric in $x,y,z$. Thus $(x*y)*z = x*(y*z)$.

**Proof of existance of identity**

$$x*0 = 0 + x + 0 = x$$
$$0*x = 0 + 0 + x = x$$

**Proof of existance of inverses**

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z}$. We need to find a $y \in \mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z}$ such that $4xy + x (-1)^y + y (-1) ^ x \equiv 0 \text{ mod } 2^n$, or equivalently

$$(4x + (-1)^x) \cdot (4y + (-1)^y) \equiv (-1) ^ {x+y} \text{ mod } 2^{n + 2}$$

Or

$$(4x(-1)^x + 1) \cdot (4y(-1)^y + 1) \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 2^{n + 2}$$

What values can be achieved with $4y(-1)^y + 1$? Taking $y = 2y'$ and $y = 2y' + 1$, we see that the possible values are exactly those of the form

$$8y' + 1 \text{ or } -8y'-3$$

Thus, the values that can be achieved with such an expression are exactly all values of the form $4a + 1$. Since the inverse of such an element in $\mathbb{Z} / 2^{n + 2} \mathbb{Z}$ is again an element of this form, we coclude that there exists a value for $y$ such that

$$(4x(-1)^x + 1) \cdot (4y(-1)^y + 1) \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 2^{n + 2}$$

As required.

**Proof of cyclicness**

It suffices to show that $1 ^ {2 ^ {n - 1}} \ne 0$.

To show that, we define the function $v_2 : (\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z}) \backslash \{0\}\to \mathbb{N}$ by $v_2 (x) = \max\{n\in\mathbb{N} : 2 ^ n | x\}$. It is easy to prove that $v_2(x*x) = v_2(x) + 1$ whenever $v_2(x) < n - 1$. Thus $v_2(1 ^ {2 ^ {n - 1}}) = n - 1$ and $1^{2^{n - 1}} \ne 0$.